# Why does infrared spectroscopy require a change in the dipole moment?

Tags: electrostatics, optics, spectroscopy, molecules

An infrared signal is generated due to fluctuations in the permanent dipole moment, but can an infrared signal be induced in a molecule due to a change in the quadrupole moment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the signals are of the order $10^{6}$ times weaker than the same for dipole transitions. This is why it is very hard to observe them.

You may want to have a read of [this](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.023091) paper.

Comment: So there would realistically be no IR signal from, say, methane because it doesn't have a permanent dipole moment?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. What is the fundamental reason why the signals are so much weaker than for dipole transitions?

Comment: Is it simply due to the dipole moment contributing so much more to the overall energy of the molecule?